# Nvidia driver is not loaded

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nvidia-settings

I know this is an Ubuntu forum, but I could really use your help since I have received 0 help from Deepin forums, and after all, we are all a big Linux family :) .

**This is the short story:
I did a fresh install of Deepin 15.4, after that `apt-get dist-upgrade` and then `apt-get install nvidia-drivers`**.

Now, when I run `lspci -vnn | egrep '3D|VGA' -A 12` 
i get the following:

---

```
3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:179c] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel modules: nvidia


00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5916] (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:1094]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
    Memory at b2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

---

If I run `nvidia-settings` i get:

---

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Error querying enabled displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: Error querying connected displays on GPU 0 (Missing Extension).


ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

---

And if I do `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver` again, i get:

`nvidia-driver is already the newest version (375.26-1+deepin)`.

---

Is this normal?? Some advice please!

**My hardware:**

Intel Core i5-7200

Nvidia Geforce 940MX

Comment: Deepin would be off topic here and your question might be closed.  Unfortunately, Deepin stopped even using Ubuntu as the base since version 15 from last year.  So, you may not get any support here as a warning.  However, if it will support the repository you can try the `graphics-drivers` repository that contains the NVIDIA drivers with decent install support.   https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Unfortunately your distribution is no (official) flavour of Ubuntu and off topic here. You can ask questions about any Linux distribution over on [Unix.SE].

Comment: Thanks for the info, and I'm sorry. Let's change to Ubuntu then :)